# Template code that compiles in gcc 8.2 but not MSVC 19

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, crtp

This example script compiles cleanly in gcc 8.2, but in Visual Studio 2019 it returns `error C3200: 'bar<int>': invalid template argument for template parameter 'bar', expected a class template` at the line where the 'new' occurs:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class bar>
class foo;

template<typename T>
class bar
{
    friend class foo<T, bar>;
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class bar>
class foo
{
};

class baz : bar<int>
{
public:
    void mash()
    {
        auto whoosh = new foo<int, bar>();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    baz A;
    A.mash();

    return 0;
}
```

Reading around, I think the problem *may* be that the second template argument in that line is now a well-defined type rather than a template, but even if that's true I don't know what to do about it. Replacing '`bar`' with '`decltype(bar)`' didn't get me anywhere.

I would welcome any suggestions.

https://godbolt.org/z/rrGdvf763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit, I don't know who is right or wrong here (see below). The confusion seems to be from the fact that inside the class template `baz` inheriting from `bar<int>` the identifier `bar` is interpreted as `bar<int>`. Strangely `bar` itself uses `bar` to refer to the template not to `bar<T>`. And the compilers do not agree. Anyhow, all compilers you included in the conformance view accept the code if you change it to:

```
class baz : bar<int>
{
public:
    void mash()
    {
        auto whoosh = new foo<int, ::bar>();
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/583nTea8j)

As Jarod42 pointed out:

> From [injected-class-name#In_class_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template): "In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a template-name of the class template itself: - it is used as a template argument that corresponds to a template template parameter". so msvc's bug.

And, thanks to aschepler for the link, the official wording in the standard can be found in [[temp.local]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.local) in paragraph 1.

So what I called "strange" above is to be expected. For example:

```
 template <typename T>
 struct moo {
      moo some_method();
      //^ refers to moo<T>
      foo<int,moo> some_other_method();
      //      ^ refers to moo
 };
```

And what you encountered is a case where msvc does not correctly implement that exception.

Comment: From [injected-class-name#In_class_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template): *"In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a template-name of the class template itself:
- it is used as a template argument that corresponds to a template template parameter"*. so msvc's bug.

Comment: Yes, thank you; that's the key to it. In my *actual* code, 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' are all within a namespace, so what I have to do is to put the explicit namespace qualifier in front of "bar>", i.e "auto whoosh = new foo<int, ns::bar>();", but then it compiles are works nicely.

Comment: I thought perhaps this was a simple matter of ambiguity, with the same symbol used both for the template parameter and the concrete class: but I tried replacing "template<typename> class bar" with "template<typename> class U" in the declaration and definition of 'foo' and that made no difference.

Comment: @EosPengwern not thats not an issue, the name of the argument doesn't matter outside of the template.

Comment: Also in the Standard itself, see [\[temp.local\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.local), paragraph 1.